# Will simple encryption be coming to 12.04

Tags: security, encryption

Will the simple encryption check box (on Ubuntu 12.10 live cd) be coming to the Ubuntu 12.04.x release?

Comment: Not sure, but I would guess not, the policy of Ubuntu releases to keep API, ABI and feature changes to a minimum within a release.

Answer (score 1):

No, 12.04 has been released and a new feature like that comes in the next release of Ubuntu.

See also:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates